# AJAX Success function if there is no returned JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I know this is simple but I am struggling to get this right. I am using jQuery/AJAX to retrieve some data (JSON) from my database. I then have a success function to display the data. This works fine but I want to have alert the user if there are no returned results.

My **PHP** excerpt which encodes the JSON:

```
...

while($row = $result->fetch_all())
{
    $returnResult = $row;
}
echo json_encode(['result' => $returnResult, 'errors' => $errors]);

....
```

My **JSON** data format looks like this:

```
{"result":[["Grade 12","Studies","John","Doe"]],"errors":false}
```

My **jQuery** that then uses the JSON data and displays in html elements:

```
function getworkload(){

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modules/getworkload.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id:id},
        cache: false,
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            if(!response.errors && response.result) {
                $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
                    $("#divwork").append('<li class="list-group-item"><b>'+value[0]+'</b> : '+value[1]+'</li>');
                    $("#spnname").html('<b>'+value[2]+' '+value[3]+' Workload </b>');
                });
            } else {
                $.each(response.errors, function( index, value) {
                    $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')
                });
            }
        });
}
```

I have tried to replace `if(!response.errors && response.result) {` with the following:

1. `if(!response.errors && response.result=null) {`
2. `if(!response.errors && !response.result) {`
3. `if(!response.errors && response.result.length < 1) {`

Comment: Why are you returning an array inside an array in the first place? Since you are overwriting `$returnResult` in each loop iteration, are we correct to assume that whatever database query you made there, it can only ever return one row at most? (And if that is the case, then what are you using a while loop for in the first place?)

Comment: try `JSON.stringify(response.result)` and then check length

Comment: Are you trying to execute the else statement if your result list is empty? In that case: if(!response.errors && response.result.length > 0) {

Comment: I get multiple rows returned, each of which then gets added to the DOM with `<li>` elements. I just gave a shorter version of the JSON format for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing errors false in your JSON, throw an HTTP error code like 404 or 500. Then, you can put an error section in your javascript instead of checking in the success section.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `JSON.parse(responce)` in success() at firstline and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the returned JSON is as follow,

```
{"result":[["Grade 12","Studies","John","Doe"]],"errors":false}
```

You just have to put one condition to check if the `result` length is `0` or not.

Like this,

```
if(!response.errors && response.result) {
                $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
                    $("#divwork").append('<li class="list-group-item"><b>'+value[0]+'</b> : '+value[1]+'</li>');
                    $("#spnname").html('<b>'+value[2]+' '+value[3]+' Workload </b>');
                });
            } else if(!response.errors && response.result && response.result.length==0) {

                 // Handle 0 result output here...

            } else {
                $.each(response.errors, function( index, value) {
                    $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')
                });
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the following but it didn't work: `else if(!response.errors && response.result && response.result.length==0) {` and `else if(!response.errors && response.result && response.result.length==null) {` and `else if(!response.errors && response.result && response.result.length=null) {` and `else if(!response.errors && response.resultt.length==0) {`

Answer (score 0):

your code is not correctly  parsing json value from `php` file to `javascript` and you have to parse `json` before  using in `javascript`

```
  function getworkload(){

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modules/getworkload.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id:id},
        cache: false,
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
             var  res = JSON.parse(response);
           console.log(res);/* console json val*/
            if(!res.errors && res .result) {
                $.each(res.result, function( index, value) {
                    $("#divwork").append('<li class="list-group-item"><b>'+value[0]+'</b> : '+value[1]+'</li>');
                    $("#spnname").html('<b>'+value[2]+' '+value[3]+' Workload </b>');
                });
            } else {
                $.each(res.errors, function( index, value) {
                    $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the server return the word 'nothing' for example in case of no result and split the code to three cases if result and if error and if nothing

```
if(isset($returnResult) && $returnResult!=null){
echo json_encode('result' => $returnResult);
}
else if (isset($errors) && $errors!=null){
echo json_encode('errors'=>$errors);
}
else { echo "nothing";}
```

Check that response is not nothing on success function

```
.success(function(response) {
if(response=='nothing'){
alert('nothing');
}
else {
//rest of the success function
}
```

Another suggestion is to use this if statement with in success function

```
.success(function(response) {
if(!response.result && !response.errors){
alert('nothing');
}
else {
//rest of the success function
}
```

Or

```
.success(function(response) {
if(response.result==null && response.errors==null){
alert('nothing');
}
else {
//rest of the success function
}
```

Comment: That is a nice answer, thank you. Unfortunately I can't really make changes to the php structure in this project because there are over 50 of them. If I were to make it from scratch I would definitely go with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP script change your `echo json_encode...` to

```
 echo json_encode(['result' => (count($returnResult)) ? $returnResult : 0, ...]);
```

Then in your JS simply do

```
if(!response.errors && !!response.result) {...
```